# How To Load Images From NSHomeDirectory

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, save

So, I'm currently saving images in my UIImageView via this method:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {

    NSString  *image1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image1.png"];
    NSString  *image2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image2.png"];
}
```

The images save just fine, but I have no idea how to set the UIImageViews images in viewDidLoad. This is what I've been trying:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[(NSHomeDirectory *)Documents objectForKey:@"image1"]];

    self.imageView2.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[(NSHomeDirectory *)Documents objectForKey:@"image1"]];
}
```

But, obviously that is not working. I'm having trouble understanding the basics here. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-imageNamed:` method looks in the application's main bundle if the named image hasn't been cached yet. From the docs:

> The name of the file. If this is the first time the image is being loaded, the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.

(See [UIImage class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a))

You want `-imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, should my viewDidLoad look like this:
`NSString *image1String = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Documents/image1" ofType:@"png"];`
    `self.imageView = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:image1String];`? I'm getting a warning "Incompatible pointer types assigning UIImageView* from UIImage".

Comment: You're close. You need to create a `UIImageView` object from the `UIImage` you just loaded with `-imageWithContentsOfFile:`. So: `self.imageView = [[[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage: [ UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath ]] autorelease ];`